# Computational complexity of function $U^V$

Tags: complexity-theory

Given $(U,V)$ two integers of finite size, I have a question about the complexity of calculating the $V^U$, i.e. $V$ raised to the power $U$. Is their a polynomial time algorithm to do this? If not is this an NP-hard problem?

Comment: see https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/37242/fixed-base-exponentiation-with-precomputations

Comment: @RickDecker I vaguely remember there was a very good answer for this question (probably by Yuval?) but couldn't found it myself. Also was too lazy to do the right thing (as you did!) and properly answering it..

Comment: What research have you done?  This is covered in standard textbooks and in Wikipedia.  What complexity model?  Number of basic operations (additions, multiplications, etc.)?  Number of bit operations?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One way to do this is by **repeated squaring**. First, express $V$ in binary,
$$
V = b_0+2^1b_1+2^2b_2+2^3b_3+\dotsm+2^nb_n
$$
where each  $b_i$ is either zero or one. Having done this, repeatedly square $U$ to get $U, U^2, (U^2)^2 = U^4, (U^4)^2=U^8, \dotsc, U^{2^n}$. Then 
$$\begin{align}
U^V&=U^{b_0+2^1b_1+2^2b_2+2^3b_3+\dotsm+2^nb_n}\\
   &=(U^{b_0})((U^2)^{b_1})((U^4)^{b_2})\dotsm((U^{2^n}))^{b_n})
\end{align}$$
For example, to compute $3^{21}$ we would get the binary expansion of $21=16+4+1$ and then repeatedly square the $3$s:

$$\begin{align}
3^1 &=3\\
3^2 &=9\\
3^4 &=81\\
3^8 &=81^2=6561\\
3^{16} &= 6561^2=43046721
\end{align}$$
So we'll have
$$
3^{21}=3^{16+4=1}=(3^{16})(3^4)(3^1)=(43046721)(81)(3)=10460353203
$$
Consider the worst case, with $V=2^n-1$, and let $d$ be the number of bits in the representation of $U$. This will require $n-1$ squarings. Let's use the grade-school multiplication algorithm, for which the product of two $k$-bit numbers will take $O(k^2)$ primitive operations. We'll then have
$$\begin{array}{ccc}
\text{product}& \text{factor size} & \text{ops needed}\\
U^2 & d & d^2\\
U^4 & 2d & 4d^2\\
    & \dotsc & \\
U^{2^{n-1}} & 2^{n-2}d & 4^{n-2}d^2
\end{array}$$
So the total number of operations needed to precompute the squares will be
$$
(1+4+4^2+\dotsm+4^{n-2})d^2 = O((2^n)^2d^2) = O(V^2\log^2U)
$$

Now since we chose $V$ so that it involved all of the squares we computed, we'll have the final product $(U)(U^2)(U^4)\dotsm(U^{2^{n-1}})$. Mirroring the construction above, we find that the final product will also take $O(V^2\log^2U)$ operations, so to compute $U^V$ by repeated squaring will take time $(2^nd^2)$ where $n, d$ are the number of bits in $V$ and $U$, respectively. Unfortunately, this means that this construction is not polynomial in the size of $V$.

**Notes**.

1. In your original question, strictly speaking, the classes P, NP, Np-complete and NP-hard are generally applied to *decision problems*, which this isn't.
2. There are faster ways to compute the product of two integers, so you can actually do better than $O(V^2\log U)$.
3. While this (as it turns out) is actually *less* efficient than the naive algorithm of computing $U^V$ by successive multiplications, $U, U^2, U^3,\dotsc$, it works very well when computing modular powers, $U^V\pmod W$, since none of the intermediate products will ever be larger than $W$.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I just need a clarification for what you mean by "primitive operations". When they define polynomial time problem set $P$, do they say what are those primitive operations? This has always confused me.

Comment: @seek. When we talk about primitive operations, we generally mean those that are essentially close to being at assembly-level, namely adding two bits or multiplying two bits. A level up would be evaluating $x<y$ for two binary numbers. This isn't quite primitive, since it would either be implemented as "subtract $x$ from $y$ and check that the result is positive or negative" or doing a comparison of the bits in the numbers, either one of which could take $O(n)$ for $n$-bit numbers. Remember, in this (log-cost) model, the numbers involved may be arbitrarily large, so we need to be aware of that

Comment: I'm not buying this. It is true that this uses $O(\log U)$ multiplications, but with repeated squaring the numbers get larger with each step and you cannot really assume that every multiplication will take $O((\log V)^2)$ operations. For example, is it really true you can compute $2^N$ with $O(\log N)$ operations, while the result takes $N$ bits to write?

Comment: @sdcvvc. Quite right. Again, I learned the truth of the maxim "Post in haste, repent at leisure". My only excuse is that it was late at night and I must have been fuzzy. I've edited my post to be closer to correct.

Comment: Seems you gave almost the same answer [before](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/37242/fixed-base-exponentiation-with-precomputations); maybe you want to consolidate the two versions over there?